# Duvída em uma Query que faz SELECT em duas tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, query

Boa tarde,
Eu estou fazendo um sistema de agendamentos de equipamento, para melhor entendimento vou colocar em tópicos algumas informações importantes.

1. Cada agendamento possui uma numeração do equipamento que vai ser utilizado naquela faixa de hora.
2. Não se pode utilizar dois equipamentos na mesma hora.
3. Cada equipamento possui um software específico instalado nele (pode estar instalado em mais que um equipamento).

E para isso estou tratando com uma função. (A minha função está uma bagunça e da vergonha de postar aqui)
Esta função está evitando os conflitos porém está ainda está com alguns problemas.

Estava tentando fazer uma query para selecionar Carros que CONTÉM o Software X e que não estão sendo usados no dia atual

SELECT DISTINCT `ls_software`.* FROM `ls_agendamentos` INNER JOIN `ls_software` ON `ls_agendamentos`.`data` = '2016-12-01' AND `ls_software`.`carro` != `ls_agendamentos`.`carro` AND `ls_software`.`nome` = 'abacate'

Esta foi a tentativa, porém essa query retorna todos os carros que estão sendo utilizado no dia de hoje

Segue a foto das tabelas para melhor entendimento exemplo.

[image: Tabela de Agendamentos]
[image: Tabela de Software]

Answer (score -2):

Tente a seguinte Query:

```
SELECT ls_software.* 
FROM ls_agendamentos 
INNER JOIN ls_software 
ON ls_software.id = ls_agendamentos.carro 
WHERE ls_agendamentos.data != '2016-12-01'
AND ls_software.nome = 'Abacate'
```